# Chrome doesn't respect camelcase for svg element "clippath"

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating a clipPath element to add to an svg.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var clipElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'clipPath');
svg.appendChild(clipElement);
```

When rendered to the dom, it changes the element to lowercase clippath, which isn't recognized by the svg (must be camelcased as clipPath).

I am looking for a way to force Chrome to respect the camelcase.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "isn't recognized by the svg"?  For me, everything [works as expected](http://jsbin.com/xuyituwu/2/edit):

```
<html>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle r="100" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
    <rect width="90" height="90" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var clipPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","clipPath");
    clipPath.id="clip";
    clipPath.appendChild(document.querySelector("rect"));
    document.querySelector("svg").appendChild(clipPath);
    alert(clipPath.nodeName);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why the Elements panel of the Dev-Tools shows the node name without camel case, but it seems this does not have to disturb you.  The `nodeName` property is still camel case, and also serializing the document will yield camel case.